# Trying to run a simple Microsoft WPF application on Debian 9

Tags: debian, .net

Given:
Visual Studio 2019 WPF .Net Core 3.1 application output in bin folder
Linux Debian 9
Wine

I'm trying to run my simple WPF application in Debian 9 but am having some challenges.

```
cd /media/psf/Home/Downloads/NewProductWpf
sudo dotnet WpfApp1.dll
```

gives this error message

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
  - No frameworks were found.

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.9-x64
```

Comment: You may be able to run the program (if it is .net), using mono. I Don't think this will fix you problem hence just a comment.

Comment: As far as i remember, Linux .Net doesnt run everything. There are things not available under Linux. Windows Desktop App should be oneof them. There should be a general class for that. Search in duck.com for Linux Windows .net crossplatform developement.